# Why won't the new update show in the App Store?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was able to update to version 0.15.0 on my iPad Mini. But on my other iPad the update won't show in the App Store. Now I can't update to the newest version to play with my friend.

Comment: The update just came out a few days ago. Wait some time for the App Store to roll out the update for all devices. this is done to reduce the load on the servers and allow a smooth update experience.

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me (multiple times), I tried restarting my tablet, deleting the app and reinstalling it, or just waiting. Sometimes my friends or brother would get the update and I would freak out, then the next day it would show up. Try doing some of the things I list below:
-wait
-restart your device (multiple times if needed)
-delete minecraft and then reinstall
-try searching online for the update 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

The new update doesn't work so you might want to wait anyway 
I update on my iPad but it dosn't work when you try to go on a world

Comment: Hi user!  This post is from four months ago, and there's been at least two app updates since then. I don't believe these two issues are related.

Answer (score -2):

No, that is incorrect. Go to MCPEBox and you will find every latest update from 0.14.3-1.1.0. Deleting the app and reinstalling it to update it will just delete all your data in the game, all that hard work DOWN THE DRAIN. If you want to keep your data AND update, update at MCPEBox.